# Elegant data model for UITableViewDataSource

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a model that essentially stores contact info: phone, twitter, address, etc.
I need to show that data in a UITableView, so I need essentially 3 pieces of information: a label ("Phone"), the actual data ("(123) 456-789") and a URL to handle that data with the right application ("tel://whatever").

I was thinking of using 3 arrays, one for each piece of info, and going through each attribute, see if it's given (could be optional), and if so, add stuff to the 3 arrays for that attribute.

Then, in the data source for the table view, each row can reference an index in the 3 arrays to populate the cell.

The order is important so I can show address before phone, etc.

Can anyone come up with a more elegant way to design the model so that I may not need 3 arrays, or lots of:

```
if(self.phone != nil)
{
  [labels addObject:@"foo"];
  [descs addObject:self.phone];
  [urls addObject:@"baz"];
}
```

There will only be one "Contact" that can have a varying number of attributes, depending on some outside condition. So each attribute is optional. The table view will show the attributes of that one contact, in a certain order.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should create a model class, with properties for each attribute. Otherwise this will come back and bite your ass some day.

Storing the values in an array, means you have stored presentational meaning into the model. Breaking the MVC pattern.

This also means you can have some actual logic in your model object, which will reduce potential defects allot. As an example:

```
// Contact.h
@interface Contact : NSObject {
}
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString* phoneNumber;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSURL phoneNumberURL;
@end

// Contact.m
@implementation Contact
@synthesize phoneNumber;
-(NSURL*)phoneNumberURL {
    return [NSURL URLWithString:
        [@"tel:" stringByAppendingString:self.phoneNumber]];
}
@end
```

This way you do not have to update the URLs from outside the model object. The model object should be able to derive this information itself. This will ensure that your application logic is not spread out into dozens of different places, but are kept in well defined pockets of logic that are easy to maintain.

Comment: I already do have a model, so that part is a given. I also get the custom getter to format it as I want. The problem is that I also need to associate a label with that attribute.
Finally, I want to easily pass that data to the table view as data source, so arrays would be nice because I can just pass them the indexPath.row. This last bit was the point of the question so I can avoid if(indexPath.row == 1) { bla } else if(indexPath.row == 2) {foo }.
Thanks though!